# Why am i getting error "call of overloaded 'abs(long long unsigned int)' is ambiguous"?

Tags: c++

so i tried to compile the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    vector<int> nums;
    while(n--){
        int temp;
        cin>>temp;
        nums.push_back(temp);
    }
    long long sum=0;
    for(int i:nums){
        sum+=i;
    }
    int index;
    long long temp_sum=0,avgdiff=0,min_avgdiff=LLONG_MAX;
    for(int i=0;i<nums.size();i++){
        temp_sum+=nums[i];
        if(i!=nums.size()-1) avgdiff=abs((temp_sum/(i+1))-((sum-temp_sum)/(nums.size()-i-1)));
        else avgdiff=temp_sum/(i+1);    
        if(min_avgdiff>avgdiff){
            min_avgdiff=avgdiff;
            index=i;
        }
    }
    cout<<index;

    return 0;
}
```

after which i got an error like this at line 22(the longest line in the code): "error: call of overloaded 'abs(long long unsigned int)' is ambiguous".

but when i modified my code as shown below:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    vector<int> nums;
    while(n--){
        int temp;
        cin>>temp;
        nums.push_back(temp);
    }
    long long sum=0;
    for(int i:nums){
        sum+=i;
    }
    int index;
    long long temp_sum=0,avgdiff=0,min_avgdiff=LLONG_MAX;
    for(int i=0;i<nums.size();i++){
        temp_sum+=nums[i];
        long long avg1=temp_sum/(i+1),avg2=0;
        if(i!=nums.size()-1){
            avg2=(sum-temp_sum)/(nums.size()-i-1);
        }
        avgdiff=abs(avg1-avg2);
        if(min_avgdiff>avgdiff){
            min_avgdiff=avgdiff;
            index=i;
        }
    }
    cout<<index;

    return 0;
}
```

i didn't get any error!! can anyone explain me why?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full and complete build output, copy-pasted as text. It can often contain notes or other information that could help understand the problem.

Comment: There's no additional charge for whitespace :-). That longest line would be a little less intimidating (and easier to read) if operators were aired out a bit by spaces and the statement was split over several shorter lines.

Comment: It's the types (as the error message says). The second version you are passing `long long` to `abs` and that's fine. But in the first example you are passing `unsigned long long` and there is no overload for that. The reason for the unsigned type is the presence of `nums.size()` which has unsigned type.

Comment: `error: call of overloaded 'abs(long long unsigned int)' is ambiguous` abs from `unsinged`? Is this smart?  Can `unsigned` type be a negative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`nums.size()` is an unsigned value (`size_t`), which means the whole expression `(temp_sum/(i+1))-((sum-temp_sum)/(nums.size()-i-1))` is unsigned. There's no overload of the function [`abs`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs) taking an unsigned value (specifically in your case, a `long long unsigned int`), so it doesn't know which version of the function to call.

Your second piece of code works because you assign this unsigned value into a variable with a signed type, and then call `abs` on that signed value.

Comment: now i understood it! thanks a lot for the detailed explanation.